# Python make a pandas dataframe from user input()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I would like to make a pd dataframe on copy paste data from a txt file but I have no idea how to do this. My current code has 3 different input() for each column on the dataframe and now I want the user to be able to copy paste all columns into a single input().

Example, i have an txt file that looks like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq4If.png)
And now I want to copy this text into an input() and it returns a dataframe that looks like the one above.

My current code have different inputs for each column

```
print("Enter Y values")
Y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print("Enter X1 values")
X1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print("Enter X2 values")
X2 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]


data = pd.DataFrame({"X1": X1, "X2": X2, "Y":Y})
```

Comment: what about `pd.read_csv("myFile.txt", sep="\t")`?

Comment: I want to copy and paste the text from the txt file into an input() and return a dataframe.

Comment: What's the problem your solution gives?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of your text file and then call [pandas.read_clipboard()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Read [here](https://dev.to/espoir/how-pandas-readclipboard-method-works-ake) for more info.